# Custom pagination in Microsoft Word

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2007

I'm using Word 2007, and I need first page to bi without pagination, next 7 pages of document to be I, II, III, IV... and rest of them 1, 2, 3, 4, 5.

Is this possible?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You need to divide the document into sections, then specify page numbering style for each section separately. See e.g. Microsoft instructions [Number pages differently in different sections](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/word-help/number-pages-differently-in-different-sections-HA101832542.aspx) (relates to Word 2010, but also applies to Word 2007).